# How do you run Karma after installation?

Tags: javascript, npm, karma-runner

I'm trying to use karma for different watch processes.

I installed karma globally with:

```
npm i -g karma
```

Then ran `karma start karma.conf.js` and it worked.

Now I need to install `karma` locally inside the project with

```
npm install karma
```

It seems to install it fine since I have the folder karma in `node_modules`, however, `node_modules/karma/bin/karma` seems not to be the executable file to run.

How should I run karma after installing it locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run Karma after installing it locally:

```
# Run Karma:
$ ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start
```

Typing `./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start` sucks and so you might find it useful to install karma-cli globally. You will need to do this if you want to run Karma on Windows from the command line.

```
$ npm install -g karma-cli
```

Then, you can run Karma simply by karma from anywhere and it will always run the local version.

Comment: the `-g` option install it glabally, I was using that, but now I need it running inside the project folder. I forgot to say I'm using windows (sadly). I'm having this error running first command:
`'node_modules\karma\bin\karma' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: are you forgetting the `.` character in the file path? try it with that and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, `start` is at the end.
The `.` does not work neither (it does not have the same effect on windows)

Comment: what happens when you run `which karma`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101406/discussion-between-ohhendrie-and-pablo).

Comment: I have solved it installing `karma-cli` globally, and `karma` locally

Answer (score 7):

To run locally on Windows (I'm on Windows 10), I recommend adding the following to your package.json file.

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "cd ./node_modules/karma/bin/ && karma start"
  },
```

Then from the command line, type `npm run test`

I prefer to not install a cli globally for these kinds of tools and instead run them locally from my project using a script. This way I can quickly see what version is in the dev dependencies and don't have to worry about the global version being different from the local one.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "karma": "^1.4.0"
 }
```